# SQL Deriving A Date Range When Only One Date is Known and Other Date Is In Another Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cross-apply, lead

I have a situation in which I have two tables (examples below):

[image: PersonTable]

[image: AddressTable]

As you can see, I do not have a Move Out Date. How could I create a view (SQL Server) that gives a range. For example, I will eventually need to use this view to see where each person lived when they made a purchase, but I am trying to work around the database design that would, ideally, have a MoveOutDate.

My desired results would be as follows:

[image]

From what I have read, I suspect I will have to use a CROSS APPLY here, but I have no idea how those work. I tried to do a join off of a subquery of the table, but situations where there are more than two addresses create a many to many relationship.

Comment: Check out ```LEAD/LAG``` window functions..

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for a week, and I think that might work for me! Thanks! @alexherm

Comment: It will certainly work, just need to put some effort.  Its good to have understanding of window functions in your back pocket.